# JOIN SQL query failed

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem: after running this query, a sequence number appears in the join column. Where is the mistake in the request?

```
SELECT shop, user_id, uh
FROM public.matched
JOIN useridhash uh ON uh.id = public.matched.id
GROUP BY shop, user_id, uh
```

Output of joined column

> (1,8453f368e7b252414d00a1e3a5e9974c11455fcf11a3556236f08df9a270a541)

"8453f368e7b252414d00a1e3a5e9974c11455fcf11a3556236f08df9a270a541" - is сorrect value. Tables are connected correctly, but I can not understand where this numbering and brackets come from.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all.  You are selecting three columns, getting two, and complaining that you should only have one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have 2 tables. I do JOIN the second table to the first by a certain condition. I get the result I need, outputs all the columns I need. Only in the column that I JOIN there are brackets and a serial number at the beginning as in the example

Comment: looks like you just select such type of displaying output in sql management studio or something like this

Comment: and correct way to show all columns from table is `uh.*` not just `uh`

Comment: @demo this is pgAdmi. everything seems to be ok

Comment: @demo: that is valid syntax in Postgres, however that returns a single column that is a record type. Using `uh.*` will most probably solve the problem that StaxDev seems to have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to the table alias `uh` in the select list represents the complete row from the table `useridhash` and creates a single column that is a record of type `useridhash`. If you want to see individual columns, use `uh.*`

Most probably you also don't want `uh` in the `order by`:

```
SELECT shop, user_id, uh.*
FROM public.matched
   JOIN useridhash uh ON uh.id = public.matched.id
GROUP BY shop, user_id, uh.id --<< change this to the column you want to sort by
```